# iOS Protocol - Delegate always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have two controllers. A BaseViewController and MyController. On BaseViewController I have as property an NSObject that has a Protocol

BaseViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyListener *myListener;
```

MyListener.h

```
@protocol MyListenerProtocol;

@interface MyListener : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyListenerProtocol> delegate;

@end


@protocol MyListenerProtocol;


@protocol MyListenerProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) myMethod: (int) input;

@end
```

MyController extends BaseViewController

```
@interface MyController : BaseViewController  <MyListener>
```

and in it's viewDidLoad:

```
super.myListener = [[MyListener alloc] init];
super.myListener.delegate = self;
```

in BaseViewController in a method, when called it does:

```
if (self.myListener && [self.myListener.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod:)]) {
            [self.myListener.delegate myMethod: input];
        }
```

But in this point the "self.myListener" is always nil.

What I want is to call a method in the child view controller when a BaseViewController's method is called (but only for some children view controllers, not all).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same `MyListener` instance?

Comment: Why `super` and not `self`?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I tested with both, "super" was my last try. No luck.

Comment: @rmaddy, MyController extends BaseViewController and it sets in it's super class that newly allocated instance. Why should it be another?

Answer (score 0):

Please implement a custom getter for the property named delegate, set it normally and set a breakpoint there. This way you will find the cause of the problem.

Also, be aware that a weak property will go away as soon as no other objet points to the
Object that you set as delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause (and an insanely common cause) is that your `BaseViewController` method is being called prior to `viewDidLoad`. Have you verified this is not the case?

As a note, you mean `self` in all the places you've put `super`.

Also note, in this line:

```
if (self.myListener && [self.myListener.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod:)]) {
```

There is no reason for `self.myListener &&...` If `self.myListener` is `nil`, the rest of the call will become false automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell the MyController the delegate it uses, but you tell the wrong name.

```
@interface MyController : BaseViewController  <MyListener>
```

change to:

```
@interface MyController : BaseViewController  <MyListenerProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate in `prepareForSegue` method.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    LastNameViewController *lastNameViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    lastNameViewController.delegate = self;
}
```